# Mathematica cycle (Do, Print)

Tags: plotting

I have a question: Is't possible Mathematica doesn't plot the function when the values of l1 and l2 are the same? What should I add to the cycle?

```
In[1]:= Psi1[l1_,m1_,l2_,m2_]:=Sqrt[(2*l1+1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l1,m1,Cos[theta1]]*Sqrt[(2*l2+1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l2,m2,Cos[theta2]]-Sqrt[(2*l1+1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l1,m1,Cos[theta2]]*Sqrt[(2*l2+1)/(4*Pi)]*LegendreP[l2,m2,Cos[theta1]]

In[2]:= Den1[l1_,m1_,l2_,m2_]:=1/2*Psi1[l1,m1,l2,m2]^2

In[3]:= Dens1[l1_,m1_,l2_,m2_]:=Plot3D[Integrate[Den1[l1,m1,l2,m2],{phi1,0,2*Pi},{phi2,0,2*Pi}]*Sin[theta1]*Sin[theta2],{theta1,0,Pi},{theta2,0,Pi}]

In[4]:= Do[Print[{l1,l2,Dens1[l1,m1,l2,m2]}],{l1,0,5},{l2,0,5},{m1,0,0},{m2,0,0}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function vanishes when `l1=l2` and `m1=m2` as

`Psi1[l, m, l, m]` $\mapsto$ 0.

If you want non-vanishing same-$l$ situations, you should distinguish $m1$ and $m2$.

Let's add all labeling to the plot just so it's clear:

```
Dens1[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_] := 
 Plot3D[Integrate[
    Den1[l1, m1, l2, m2], {phi1, 0, 2*Pi}, {phi2, 0, 2*Pi}]*
   Sin[theta1]*Sin[theta2], {theta1, 0, Pi}, {theta2, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Grid[{{Subscript[l, 1] -> l1, 
      Subscript[m, 1] -> m1}, {Subscript[l, 2] -> l2, 
      Subscript[m, 2] -> m2}}]]
```

Now physically $m$ can only range from -$l$ to $l$.  If you only want to print when it isn't uniformly zero you can add an if statement:

```
Do[Do[If[l1 =!= l2 || m1 =!= m2, 
   Print[{l1, l2, Dens1[l1, m1, l2, m2], m1, m2}]], {m1, -l1, 
   l1}, {m2, -l2, l2}], {l1, 0, 5}, {l2, 0, 5}]
```

yielding e.g.

[image: l1l1m-1m0 plot]

The logic in the if statement is probably clear, but in english, *only evaluate if the $l$s are different, or if the $l$s are the same as long as the $m$s are different*.

Comment: That's right. For this reason, I'm looking some Mathematica tool that excludes from the calculation all cases when l1=l2.

Comment: Are you looking for the right place to put an `If` statement?  i.e.  Only do the evaluation *if* ls are different or if m's are different?  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, man, that's what I was looking for. Since the function is antisymmetric, it makes no sense to plot the density when l1=l2, or to run another type of computation involving these cases. For a symmetric function, I'm interested in cases when l1 and l2 are the same (and different, of course) but there I have no problem. On the other hand, at this moment I'm interested in cases when m1=m2=0. Thank you very much!